# Can Beast Boy regenerate limbs?

Tags: dc, beast-boy

Beast Boy is capable of changing into many animals, including long dead dinosaurs, alien animals, and even some mythical ones. This change can be significant, including changes in mass, or limbs (monkey with an prehensile tail), or even completely new organs like fish gills. So has he ever been shown to regrow limbs, as some animals are able to, or even other things like growing teeth back like a shark?

Logically, someone that can change their DNA to suit any animal should be able to regrow limbs, change (human) features or heal wounds at will, but Beast Boy is not the smartest most creative of the bunch. So has he done anything of the like in any media?

Comment: To be fair, my exposure to BB is mostly from 3 old Teen Titans comics, and TT/TT Go/YJ

Answer (score 4):

Yes he can regrow limbs... Beastboy has been shown to heal faster by changing into the form of an animal that has accelerated healing and this means that if he stayed in the form of an animal that can regrow limbs then he would regrow it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_Boy

From the wikipedia regarding his powers

> As a result of his rapidly changing genetic
>   structure and mass, Beast Boy has an increased healing factor
>   comparable to that of The Creeper and Deathstroke, allowing him to
>   heal from bullet wounds, burns, and broken bones in a matter of
>   seconds, and in some story lines regrow entire limbs.

The best example I found was a quote but I have to find the source, a user on [comicvine](http://www.comicvine.com/beast-boy/4005-3586/forums/does-he-have-healing-582519/) says that Beastboy in one of the books shows his ability to heal.

> There have been moments where he turns into animals with excellerated
>   healing factors and waited for his injuries to heal before becoming
>   human again.  The only example of this i really remember was in the
>   Titans book.    After Jericho possesed Cyborg, he used his body to
>   beat gar senseless.  Later Cyborg goes to check on Gar and remarks how
>   surprised he is that Gar has almost completely healed. Gar explains
>   that he turned into a salamander and stayed in that form until he was
>   healed up again.    However, while in human form, I don't believe he
>   has any special healing abilities.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find a single panel or scene or even issue/book/volume number that backs that up.

Comment: True but it makes sense that if he becomes an animal he would gain it's abilities.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no canon answer to this.  It would also potentially change depending on the canon, even if there were a canon answer in one of the various bits of media Beast Boy is in.  For example, even if he were shown in Teen Titans GO! to be able to regenerate a lost limb, that wouldn't necessarily carry over to meaning that his comic incarnation could (or even his Teen Titans TV show version).

That said, Beast Boy has shown considerable flexibility in his power.  He can change form into something with many times his mass (a whale) or with significantly less mass (an insect).  He seems to be able to perfectly mimic most animals (excepting color).

It seems to me that there are two possibilities, based on his commonly displayed abilities, that the writers would have to decide between:

- Beast Boy's normal form retains injuries he suffered while in animal form (and vice versa)

  OR
- Beast Boy's normal form is restored to normal health whenever he changes shape.

Each of these would pose different difficulties for a writer.  If Beast Boy is automatically fully healed by changing form (excepting mental effects like exhaustion) then he becomes an extremely difficult person to physically harm.  If Beast Boy retains injuries between forms, what happens when he is injured on a part that doesn't have a corresponding location on his normal form?  What happens when he changes into an octopus and gets a tentacle injured?

Finally, we have to consider the role that Beast Boy plays - BB is most often the comic relief or butt monkey.  He's not the sort to brood or be dramatic.  A character like Raven or Arsenal could lose a limb and it would fit their character - they would be able to talk (to the others or the audience via thought bubbles) about what it means to lose a limb, they could evaluate their self-worth, berate their own weakness, etc.  For those characters, it would be a way to explore their roles and convey the messages they're supposed to pass along to the reader.  With Beast Boy, it wouldn't work.  Comics have tried having the happy-go-lucky goofball turn morose (I'm looking at you, [Speedball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbie_Baldwin#.22Civil_War.22)) and it has universally been a failure.

In short, Beast Boy's powers exact limitations are up to the writer and can vary by media and series.  For that reason, this question cannot be given a definitive answer unless and until the problem is presented in an official work.  That said, I expect the Beast Boy would never permanently lose a limb - he would not be able to serve his purpose in the narrative if he did.  Thus, if he ever does lose a limb in canon (with the exception of time travel/Dark Future/dreams/etc) I expect he will find a way to regain it.  It may be explained away as a one-time use of his powers (like when Superman rose from the dead) or as a wish or the result of use of some strange medical device, but he would regain it.

Comment: Arsenal lose a limb - like *that* would ever happen! :-)

Comment: @RDFozz - Arsenal is like Bucky.  Loses limbs like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In animal form he can grow back limbs or heal himself quicker over a certain time ( either instantaneous or gradually ) which is seen on Teen Titans Go! or pop culture media and storylines relating to the Teen Titans.

Comment: *"which is seen on Teen Titans Go! or pop culture media and storylines relating to the Teen Titans."* This is fairly vague, could you be more specific?

Comment: For example, tv shows, movies, tv series, comic books and storylines either mentioning them in a story ( or stories ) or actually in the story ( or stories ).

Comment: Yes.... *Which* stories though?